# After grails clean I can't run-app

Tags: grails, groovy

I did a `grails clean` and afterwards when I run via `grails run-app` the app never starts and the following is repeatedly displayed (goes on forever, stuck in some kind of loop).

I'm running Grails 1.0.4, Java 1.6 on Windows XP.

Grails is somehow stuck in an invalid configuration. Any idea how to restore it?

```
  [groovyc] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\Steve\.grails\1.0.4\projects\myproject\classes
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\Steve\.grails\1.0.4\projects\myproject\classes
2008-12-28 10:40:27.549:/myproject:INFO:  Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
[6688] spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext Closing org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1c3c6d8: display name [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1c3c6d8]; startup date [Sun Dec 28 10:40:23 PST 2008]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@93912f
2008-12-28 10:40:27.549:/myproject:INFO:  Shutting down log4j
  [groovyc] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\Steve\.grails\1.0.4\projects\myproject\classes
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\Steve\.grails\1.0.4\projects\myproject\classes
2008-12-28 10:40:27.877::INFO:  jetty-6.1.12
2008-12-28 10:40:27.892::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2008-12-28 10:40:27.970:/myproject:INFO:  Set web app root system property: 'myproject-development-0.1' = [C:\dev\myproject\web-app]
2008-12-28 10:40:27.970:/myproject:INFO:  Initializing log4j from [file:C:\Documents and Settings\Steve/.grails/1.0.4/projects/myproject/resources/log4j.properties]
2008-12-28 10:40:27.970:/myproject:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[7297] spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext Refreshing org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1ada1e0: display name [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1ada1e0]; startup date [Sun Dec 28 10:40:27 PST 2008]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@18b24cb
[7297] spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext Bean factory for application context [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1ada1e0]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cf6930
2008-12-28 10:40:27.299:/myproject:INFO:  Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
2008-12-28 10:40:27.314::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I tracked it down. I had a single .java file that was completely commented out. This is 100% legal as far as Java is concerned but apparently Grails can't handle it. Grails must be assuming that any .java will have a corresponding .class files. Since the file contained no Java code, it produced no corresponding class file.

**Follow-up**: This has been fixed in 2.0-M2, see [GRAILS-3763](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3763)

Comment: i think it might be good to add a jira (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS ) in for that (if one doesnt exist)